# JavaScript detect CSS animation in progress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm having some trouble in my JavaScript deciding whether to wait for `animationend` events or not and wondered if an elegant solution to this problem exists.

Lets say that I have a div that animates on page load and fades in, then at a later time I have another script that appends an `<img>` tag to the div.

I want the `<img>` to be appended *after* the animation has completed in order to avoid any stuttering during the animation and to just make it look nicer.

Currently I know that I can write something like this (assuming I use animate.css):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="append-image-here animated fadeIn"></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function() {
  $('.append-image-here').one([
    'webkitAnimationEnd',
    'mozAnimationEnd',
    'MSAnimationEnd',
    'oanimationend',
    'animationend'
  ].join(' '), function() {
    $('<img>', { src: '/image.jpg' }).appendTo(this);
  });
});
```

This is fine if the script runs before the animation completes and the `animationend` event fires, but if the script happens to run after the animation ends the `<img>` tag will never be created and will never be appended to the div (for example if the handler was set in a timeout or something like that which ran past the animation duration).

Is there any way to detect if a CSS animation is currently running so the script can decide whether to wait for the `animationend` or not without having to rely on user added classes or data attributes?

(I ask to not rely on classes and attributes because if I'm working with someone else's animations I may not know the classes ahead of time)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: maybe of interest: http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-animation-javascript-event-handlers/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just using `.on()` on the document and even check which animation has just 
finished and which element was animated (`e.target`) The event handler will attached before the DOM is fully loaded and CSS animation are fired.

DEMO: [**JSnippet Demo**](https://www.jsnippet.net/snippet/250/JavaScript-detect-CSS-animation-in-progress)

Note: do not attach when DOM ready - `$(function(){ ... })`

```
$(document).on([
    'webkitAnimationEnd',
    'mozAnimationEnd',
    'MSAnimationEnd',
    'oanimationend',
    'animationend'
    ].join(' '), function(e) {
       //Do whatever you want 
       console.log(e);
       $('ul').append(
          "<li>Animation end detected on: "  
          + e.target 
          + "." + e.target.className + 
          "</li>"
       );
});
```

```js
$(function(){
  
    $('button').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('animate');
    });
    
});

$(document).on([
    'webkitAnimationEnd',
    'mozAnimationEnd',
    'MSAnimationEnd',
    'oanimationend',
    'animationend'
  ].join(' '), function(e) {
    //Do whatever you want 
    console.log(e);
    $('ul').append(
        "<li>Animation end detected on: "  
        + e.target 
        + "." + e.target.className + 
        "</li>"
    );
    $('button').removeClass('animate');
});
```

```css
button {
        width: 300px;
        background-color: red;
}
button.animate {
        -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        animation-name: example;
        animation-duration: 1s;
}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    from {background-color: red;}
    to {background-color: yellow;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
    from {background-color: red;}
    to {background-color: yellow;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="animate">Trigger animation</button>
<ul></ul>
```

Comment: It's funny how sometimes we don't see the obvious things. It was right in front of me the whole time; I feel slightly embarrassed that I didn't think of this in the first place :)

Comment: It happens to me all the time (over thinking)... But its a good question that may help others, Have fun.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not answer the question "how to detect if a CSS animation is in progress" (short of keeping track of every start/end event)